# How to auto start electron app after app quit

Tags: electron

In my case after synchronization process finished from backend server app will quit as per below code.

```
 app.quit();
```

But after that i need to run app again by manually clicking on (.exe). Now i am looking for solution that can start app automatically after app quit.

Answer (score 1):

`app.relaunch();
 app.exit();`

this will restart your app.

Answer (score 1):

I solved issue by changing code as below

```
ipcMain.on("exit-app", event => {
      if (process.platform !== "darwin") {
        app.quit();
        app.relaunch({ args: process.argv.slice(1).concat(['--relaunch']) })
        app.exit(0)
      }
});
```